# Is it possible to use another circuit breaker over fallback method?

Tags: spring-boot, design-patterns, microservices, spring-cloud, circuit-breaker

I have a requirement to implement circuit breaker in  a java based microservice such that if there are defined number of failures from **backendA** then fallback method should call to another **backendB**, and if **backendB** also fails then there should be another fallback method to return error from Java API itself.Is it possible, more importantly is it advisable to implement such design.If someone can give any reference or examples where such patterns is used. I will be using **resilience4j** library to do so. The code structure will look something like this:

```
@CircuitBreaker(name = "backendA", fallbackMethod = "fallback1")
{Method to call backendA}//Threshold value : 10 requests

@CircuitBreaker(name = "backendB", fallbackMethod = "fallback2")
private String fallback1() { Method to call backendB} // Threshold value : 2 requests


private String fallback2() { Method to return error}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating another class and a new method to call the alternate system worked for me. Basically a circuit breaker cannot be applied on the fallback method in the same class, so calling another method in a new class and adding a Circuit breaker there, resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This won't work due to the way Spring AOP (proxies) work.
A fallback method cannot have Annotations.

Comment: yes I am facing the same issue. But then is it not possible to call another service using the custom fallback method, because the alternate service may also fail and in that case how is the system suppose to behave?